# Split by comma while ignoring special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split it comma but not the escaped string. Also remove slash from it.

```
var str = "02-Dentist,\"***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016\",Riverside,888-885-6112,5,1,20.00%,1690000"
```

Current Output

```
["02-Dentist,\"***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016\",Riverside,888-885-6112,5,1,20.00%,1690000"
```

Expected Output

```
["02-Dentist","***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016","Riverside","888-888-9999","5","1","20.00%","1690000"]
```

Tried Code

```
var replaced = str.replace(/[^\\],/,"$09").split("$09")
```

Comment: Your string `str` has no backslashes and the regex matches a `,` that is preceded with any char other than ``\`` (also consumed).

Comment: Okay so can you give a solution for it. I dont know regex

Comment: Sorry, I do not find the question very clear. Try `var chunks= str.match(/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^,]+/g);`

Comment: two time double quotes `["02-Dentist", ""***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016"", "Riverside", "888-885-6112", "5", "1", "20.00%", "1690000"]`

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/86qjjry7/ for an alternative.

Comment: Okay this gives the result but are you sure this is the only efficient way to achieve my expected output? Because whatever you wrote will take me time to understand it. Bit complex or it is because i don't know regex :(

Comment: I will post an answer to explain every bit of it

Comment: that would be of a great help :)

Comment: One question: can you have `"` in the fields that are not inside double quotes?

Comment: I think i did not get you properly. Everything is inside the double quotes.

Comment: Have a look at [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YPRTR/2). Could you please test your sample strings there to see if there is anything not working as expected?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133364/discussion-between-node-saini-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to tokenize a string into what is between double quotes, or between commas. I assume the fields are delimited with commas, and may be enclosed with double quotes with escaped quotes/entities inside.

You may use

```js
var m,res = [];
var str = "02-Dentist,\"***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016\",Riverside,888-885-6112,5,1,20.00%,1690000";
var re = /"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|[^,]+/g;
while((m=re.exec(str)) !== null){
  if (m[1]) 
    res.push(m[1]);
  else  
    res.push(m[0]); 
}
console.log(res);
```

The pattern is:

```
/"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|[^,]+/g
```

See [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YPRTR/1). It  matches the double quoted substring together with any escape entities inside and *captures* what is in between the quotes (with `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"`) and also matches 1+ characters other than `,` with `[^,]+`.

With `if (m[1])`, we can check if Group 1 matched and if yes, the contents inside Group 1 (`m[1]`) is pushed to the final array. If not, the whole match value is pushed to the array (`m[0]`).

If there are no escape entities in your input, you may even use

```
/"([^"]*)"|[^,]+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1YPRTR/3)

Comment: If there are escape entities even then this regex works `/"([^"]*)"|[^,]+/g`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "02-Dentist,\"***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016\",Riverside,888-885-6112,5,1,20.00%,1690000";
var result = str.split(/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: `"\"***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016\""` should be like `"***IN-Den-WV,VA,SC,TN,LA-122016"`